# Why is G a cycle? Graph G with n vertices, m edges. "(∀v ∈ V(G) : δ(v) = 2 ⇒ G is Hamiltonian) is true because G is a cycle".

Tags: graph-theory, cyclic-groups, hamiltonian-path

I'm reviewing an earlier exam with solutions by the professor. I found this:

> Problem: Let G denote a simple, connected graph with n vertices and m edges.
>   Translate the following statement to English and tell whether it is
>   true or false.

```
∀v ∈ V(G) : δ(v) = 2 ⇒ G is Hamiltonian.
```

> Solution: If the degree of each vertex is equal to 2, then G is Hamiltonian.
>   True (because G is a cycle).

But how does the professor know that G is a cycle? Couldn't G contain two components? Is it a mistake?

Comment: The text of the exercise states that the graph is connected.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. But connected-> cycle? what about graph with V := {a,b,c} and E := {<a,b>,<b,c>}?

Comment: Your example fails because neither $a$ nor $c$ have degree 2.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Does degree 2 for all vertices imply cycle?

Comment: Yes. See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390030/let-g-be-a-graph-in-which-every-vertex-has-degree-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_0$ be any vertex.
Let $v_1$ be one of $v_0$'s neughbours.
Then recursively let $v_{k+1}$ be the neighbour of $v_k$ that is not $v_{k-1}$.
This sequence is eventually periodic because $G$ is finite. As $v_{k-1}$ is also uniquely determind by $v_k$ and $v_{k+1}$, the sequence is in fact periodic so that we obtain a cycle. Do yo see why this cycle is all of $G$?